# Go function that return overall status

Tags: go

The code does the following:

1. getting array of installation status and provide some overall status which is string value
2. loop on the array and if there is one of the installation entry is error all the installations consider as error and return `overallstatus=error`
3. if one is running the `overallstatus=running`
4. otherwise `overallstatus=installing`

My question is if there a **simpler/shorter** to write it in go?

```
func overallInstallationStatus(installStatus []apiv.Installstatus) string {
    overallStatus := ""
    for _, status := range installStatus {
        switch status.ReleaseStatus {
        case release.StatusFailed.String():
            // If at least one installation is in failed, we consider the overallstatus to be in error state
            overallStatus = "error"
        case release.StatusDeployed.String():
            // If no other status was found and there is at least one deployed chart, we consider it "running"
            if overallStatus == "" {
                overallStatus = "running"
            }
        default:
            // All other statuses are considered to be "installing"
            if overallStatus != release.StatusFailed.String() {
                overallStatus = "installing"
            }
        }
    }
    return overallStatus
}
```

Comment: If at least one is running from the list without errors, status is `running` or all  all should be running without errors for `running` ?
Just to clarify my answer

Comment: @nipuna - if one have error the status should be error,oterwise installing or running

Comment: yes, that is clear. What is `status running` ? At least on is running without errors or all are running without errors?

Comment: @nipuna all running without of error

Comment: Okay, I have edited the answer. this can be simplified. Please check there

Comment: Sure thanks Im creating ut and will check it in 20-30 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be simplified and shortened:

```
 func overallInstallationStatus(installStatus []apiv.Installstatus) string {
    overallStatus := "running"
    for _, status := range installStatus {
        switch status.ReleaseStatus {
        case release.StatusFailed.String():
              //If at least one installation is in failed, we consider the overallstatus to be in error state 
              return "error"
        case release.StatusDeployed.String():
              //If no other status was found and there is at least one deployed chart, we consider it "running"
              continue
        default:
              //All other statuses are considered to be "installing"
              overallStatus = "installing"
        }
    }
    return overallStatus
 }
```